# Necesito ayuda con la eliminación de datos junto a sus registros relacionados en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

estoy intentando crear una querie para eliminar unos datos de una tabla llamada sucursal, pero al momento de eliminarlos también debo eliminar las relaciones que se tienen exactamente con esos datos.

estoy haciendo algo como esto.

```
UPDATE empleado SET numSucursal = 0 WHERE numSucursal = 2;
DELETE FROM sucursal WHERE numSucursal = 2;
```

funciona pero creo que esta incorrecto hacerlo de esta forma.

las tablas son estas

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sucursal(
    numSucursal int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

y esta

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleado(
    numEmpleado int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    sueldo bigint NOT NULL,
    fContratacion DATE NOT NULL,
    numSucursal int,
    jefe int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkjefe
    FOREIGN KEY (jefe) REFERENCES empleado(numEmpleado),
    CONSTRAINT fksucursal
    FOREIGN KEY (numSucursal) REFERENCES sucursal(numSucursal)
);
```

El error surge cuando intento borrar la fila, me dice
ERROR 1451: 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

No he logrado dar con la solucion.

Necesito su ayuda, Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: ¿Hay mas tablas que dependan de la tabla sucursal?

Comment: Hola, solamente la de los empleados, ya que al crear un empleado debo asignarle una sucursal.

Comment: Tienes el autocommit de la bd deshabilitado?

Comment: Empece hace poco con sql, investigare esa funcionalidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error te da por que la tabla empleados con la llave foránea de la sucursal te impide borrar una sucursal que tiene relaciones con otras tablas, necesitas borrar la referencia de la tabla empleados y volverla a crear con un on delete cascade para que te permita borrar pero **OJO** perderás todos los registros de la tabla empleados asociados a la sucursal. Aqui te dejo un pequeño codigo pero **solo ejecutalo en caso de que quieras borrar tambien a los empleados, en caso contrario la manera en que lo haces es la correcta para no perder esos registros**

```
alter table empleado
drop constraint fksucursal;

alter table empleado
add constraint fksucursal
foreign key (numSucursal)
references sucursal(numSucursal)
on delete cascade;
```

Cabe destacar que esa restricción es por seguridad para evitar precisamente borrar datos no deseados, lo recomendable siempre sera tener esta acción des habilitada

Answer (score 0):

Puedes evitar la revision de las restricciones de las claves foráneas

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Ahora realizas el delete y verás como no te da error

```
DELETE FROM sucursal WHERE numSucursal = 2;
```

Después activas la revisión de las restricciones de nuevo

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```